# How to get HTML before its sent to the browser

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I would like to capture HTML before its gets sent to the browser for caching. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I thought MVC 3 had output caching built in with [OutputCache(Durantion=100000)] as an attribute on the action?

Comment: I don't believe so (not sure). Because when you start to use `Response.OutputStream` headers are sent, and then the content you are writing to the stream. Cant you cache the stuff that you are sending, before you actually write it to the OutputStream?

Comment: The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.aspx) seems to imply that you can use the `Buffer` and/or `BufferOutput` properties to cause the `HttpResponse` to buffer its content while the request is being processed.  Perhaps you could do that, and then inspect the buffered data at the end of the request processing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've never tried this, but could you hook into the [EndRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication.endrequest.aspx) event of an HTTP module, and simply read the Response property?

Edit: Just tried this - massive fail, at least at a simple level, because the Response isn't readable at that point. Could still be viable if there's a way to redirect the output of the Response at the beginning of a request, and then pipe it through at the end.

Edit #2: I was close, but it's more complex than I thought. You need to implement a filter, which is demonstrated nicely [here](http://aspnetresources.com/articles/HttpFilters).